# Split a JS array into multiple arrays by a comparison function

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here's a pattern I've been reusing in my Javascript a few times, enough that I ended up writing this function for it, using Underscore's `groupBy`:

```
var sliceBy = function(array, comparison){
        var sliceCounter = 0;
        var slices = _(array).groupBy(function(b, i){
            var a = array[i - 1];
            return i === 0 ? 0 :
                   sliceCounter += comparison(a, b);
        });
        return _(slices).values();
    };
```

It iterates through the array, comparing each `b` value to its previous `a` value, and determining whether to group `b` in an array with `a` or to start a new array. Since `groupBy` is expecting its iteratee to return a value corresponding to, well, how to group stuff by, I have to use `sliceCounter` to keep track of this.

Specifically, I'm using this algorithm for two main purposes: to group consecutive points in an array of not-necessarily-consecutive points (i.e `b.x === a.x + 1`), and to group which paths in an array of SVGs overlap each other.

What I'm worried about is that this feels like a common enough problem that I shouldn't be the first person to write an algorithm for it, yet I haven't been able to find any libraries that provide a function to split an array by a comparison function. My question is:

1. Is there a CS name for this type of operation, in the same pantheon as `map`, `reduce`, `filter`, `sort`, etc.?
2. Is there a more performant way of doing this? (Which is sort of related to question 1, because knowing the answer to that would make it easier to research)

Comment: I am a little lost. Where are you defining `_` and what does it do?

Comment: It might be a good idea to provide an array used as input and the required output in your question.

Comment: Ok I get it you are using a framework. Time find it and take it appart.

Comment: *Is there a CS name for this type of operation*, `group by`, which happens to be the name of the function in underscore you are using.